# How can I extract semi structured tables from PDF using pdfplumber

Tags: python, pdf, extract, pdfplumber

I want to extract semi structured tables from PDF files. I might consider other modules than pdfplumber if they can work better. I need not only table, but sometimes text above table is still a part of the table (for example name of columns sometimes are above table), or table is continued on the other page.

I tried using extract_text_lines() and It works fine. I want to check pdf line by line and if line is a table - I start collecting this data.

```
def extract_table_from_page(pdf_path, page_number):

    with pdfplumber.open(pdf_path) as pdf:

        page = pdf.pages[page_number]
        lines = page.extract_text_lines()
        for line in lines:
            if 'chars' in line.keys():
                print(line)
```

Comment: You may want to consider PyMuPDF, which has an advanced table detector. It can detect column headers even if they are outside table gridlines. **Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/). Just as a friendly hint: **_nobody_** will ever look at such a dump of long cryptic output .

Comment: @JorjMcKie Can u please give me a hint which function It will be? I also have text outside table gridlines which is vertical, is there also a way to extract this as a column name? Thank you :)

Comment: You can do `tabs = page.find_tables()`. The returned object `tabs` contains a list of tables AOT. Your other question depends on the concrete example.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a ***PyMuPDF*** example of a table having external column headers in a number of different header text rotation angles - including multi-line column headers.

Some of the column names are vertical.
[image]

Here is a PyMuPDF script which finds and extracts the table, identifies the column names and prints table contents in markdown format (Github-compatible):

```py
import fitz  # PyMuPDF
doc=fitz.open("input.pdf")  # test file
page=doc[0]  # first page having the table
tabs=page.find_tables()  # find tables on page
tab=tabs[0]  # take first table
print(tab.to_markdown())  # print all content in Github-markdown format

|Column1|column2|column3 line 2|column4 line 2|
|---|---|---|---|
|11|22|33|44|
|55|66|77|88|
|99|AA|BB|CC|
|DD|EE|FF||


tab.header.external  # show some table header properties
True

tab.header.names
['Column1', 'column2', 'column3 line 2', 'column4 line 2']
```

BTW: Other formats are available too, like a Python list of lists or output to pandas DataFrame.

**Note:** I am a maintainer and the original creator of [PyMuPDF](https://pypi.org/project/PyMuPDF/).

Comment: When I print tab.to_markdown() i get "AttributeError: 'Table' object has no attribute 'to_markdown'".

Comment: @Alex upgrade to version 1.24.0 of PyMuPDF - or use another output option for table!